# Update Image and Another Field in PHP my sql table

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I am updating image using below command and its working fine. Is there any way to update one more column in the table at the same time. There is one more column in which I need to update image description like Human, Animals,Aliens etc.... How to perform this function?

Below Code:

```
if($_POST["action"] == "insert")
{
$file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images(name) VALUES ('$file')";
if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
{
echo 'Image Inserted into Database';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your insert query like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images(name, description) VALUES ('$file', '$description')";
```

Note: You can insert more than one values in a single insert query.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Comment: Below is the code, I have used in my sample page. How to pass the value from one page to another.  http://www.webslesson.info/2017/06/ajax-image-add-edit-remove-from-mysql-database-using-php.html

Comment: Don't use MySQL, it is deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.  If you need the implementation, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT INTO statement is used to insert new records in a table.

**INSERT INTO Syntax**

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

**ex -**

```
INSERT INTO tbl_images (name, dessc) VALUES ($file, $desc);
```